# OpenCV How to initialize Mat with 2D array in JAVA

Tags: opencv, multidimensional-array, mat

Suppose, I have a 2D array initialized with values, how do I put this value in a Mat object in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry don't know about Java but can suggest the general logic. In C++ openCV we do it by 2 `for loops` as following:

```
matObject.create( array.rows, array.cols, CV_8UC1 ); // 8-bit single channel image

for (int i=0; i<array.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<array.cols; j++)
    {
         matObject.at<uchar>(i,j) = array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Let me know if it was your query..

Comment: What is the alternative for matObject.at<uchar>(i,j) = array[i][j]; in JAVA? I can't find anything.

Comment: sorry i don't know about java...but it is just a method to access the pixel at location (i,j) and this is the basic thing in image processing so should be very very easy. In `matObject.at<uchar>(i,j) = array[i][j];`, we are just accessing the image's pixel at `(i,j)` and putting a value at that location. PS: Do not forget to do the proper typecast. If the values stored in array are of integer type then `matObject.at<uchar>(i,j) = (uchar)array[i][j];`

Answer (score 5):

probably something like this will work:

```
float trainingData[][] = new float[][]{ new float[]{501, 10}, new float[]{255, 10}, new float[]{501, 255}, new float[]{10, 501} };
Mat trainingDataMat = new Mat(4, 2, CvType.CV_32FC1);//HxW 4x2
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        trainingDataMat.put(i,0, trainingData[i]);
```

Code is self explanatory: you have the data in the "TrainingData" array, and you allocate the new Mat object. Then you use the "put" method to push the rows in place.

Answer (score 0):

Is matObject a keyword or it means we have to substitute with the name of the Mat image?
For example if I have defined an image as:

Mat inputImage = imread ("C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\My Pictures\Images\imageName.jpg");

then should I put inputImage instead of  matObject?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use put method of Mat for this.
Code

```
int[][] intArray = new int[][]{{2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8,9,10}};
Mat matObject = new Mat(3,3,CvType.CV_8UC1);
for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
   for(int col=0;col<3;col++)
        matObject.put(row, col, intArray[row][col]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use to

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat array= Highgui.imread("java.png" ,CvType.CV_8UC1 );
    Mat matObject = new Mat();
    matObject.create( array.rows(), array.cols(),CvType.CV_8UC1 );

    for (int i=0; i<array.rows(); i++)
    {

        for(int j=0; j<array.cols(); j++)
        {

           matObject.put(i, j, array.get(i, j));

        }
    }

    Highgui.imwrite("java2.jpg", matObject);
```