# how to import a mat value in openCV

Tags: java, opencv, import, mat

I exported many CalcHist mat-values into a file and build an average of the values. Now I want to import it back into my Java Programm (static in the Code or import as file, it doesn't matter) to compare the calculated average hist with a hist of an given Image. The problem is that I don't know how to import the values into a Mat variable.

Example hist-values:

```
[680.365; 898.065; 583.155; 971.535; 454.825; 202.34; 213.26; 316.98; 449.765; 9902.57; 357078.595; 1292.21; 521.705; 157.985; 109.985; 137.685; 301.395; 127.58; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
```

If I implement it as a static value with MatOfDouble (I don't have an idea to do it in another way) like this:

```
MatOfDouble averageHist= new MatOfDouble(680.365, 898.065, 583.155, 971.535, 454.825, 202.34, 213.26, 316.98, 449.765, 9902.57, 357078.595, 1292.21, 521.705, 157.985, 109.985, 137.685, 301.395, 127.58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I can use the variable for a compareHist like this:

```
 double res= Imgproc.compareHist(baseHist, averageHist, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);
```

and compile it, but at runtime it will throw a exception.

the programm works, if I only use Mat values that I directly get from calchists like the variable baseHist, but for averageHist I want to put it static in the Code or read it from a file.

I tried to cast the MatOfDouble into a normal Mat like this:

```
Mat averSunnyHistCast = new Mat();
averSunnyHistCast = (Mat) averageHist;
```

but it doesn't help.

this is the error:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:2281: error: (-215) H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.depth() == CV_32F in function cv::compareHist
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This post helped: [OpenCV How to initialize Mat with 2D array in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812490/opencv-how-to-initialize-mat-with-2d-array-in-java)

I wrote my values static in an array, after that I added each value into the Mat variable with the put method.

```
double[] dblArr =  {650, 1230, 257, 66, 38, 19, 20, 33, 75, 15617, 350640, 2737, 1251, 547, 325, 328, 417, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
Mat averageHist = new Mat(25, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
for (int i=0; i<25; i++){
    averSunny200.put(i, 0, dblArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: notice: "25;" should be the array length. So in the example (in Java) averageHist.length