# Converting Mat to one dimensional float array for EM?

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to convert a Python code to Java. However, I'm unable to find a way to create the sample to train the Expectation Maximization as it should be a one-channel matrix with 2 values (S and V from HSV Color Space) as below:

- row 0: S, V
- row 1: S, V
- row 2: S, V
- row 3: S, V

In Python, I was able to do it as follow:

```
def convert_to_samples(image, height, width):
    samples = []
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            samples.append(image[y, x])
    samples = np.float32(np.vstack(samples))
    return samples
```

I have tried as following without success as the result is not a `Mat` and I can't find a way to transform it back.

```
public double[][] convert_to_samples(Mat image) {
    double[][] samples = new double[image.height()][];
        for(int i = 0; i < image.height(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < image.width(); j++) {
                samples[i] = image.get(i, j);
            }
        }
    return sortRowWise(samples);
}

private static double[][] sortRowWise(double[][] m) {
    for (double[] values : m) Arrays.sort(values);
    return m;
}
```

Could someone help me transform the Mat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812490/opencv-how-to-initialize-mat-with-2d-array-in-java. Please see the second answer (not the accepted one).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Mat convert_to_samples(Mat image) {
    double[][] samples = new double[image.height()][];
    for(int i = 0; i < image.height(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < image.width(); j++) {
            samples[i] = image.get(i, j);
        }
    }
    sortRowWise(samples);
    Mat matSamples = new Mat(image.height(), 2, CvType.CV_64FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.height(); i++) {
        matSamples.put(i, 0, samples[i]);
    }
    return matSamples;
}

private static void sortRowWise(double[][] m) {
    for (double[] values : m) Arrays.sort(values);
}
```